# Ayuda con una consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo dos tablas y quiero hacer una consulta como se muestra en la imagen anexada.
Intente hacerlo de esta forma:

```
SELECT semana, num_eqpo_loc, goles_loc, num_eqpo_vis, goles_vis, (goles_loc = goles_vis) AS Ganador
FROM partidos;
```

¿cómo podría mostrar el nombre de los equipos? y ¿de qué forma podría determinar el equipo que gano y si es empate?

```
CREATE TABLE `equipos` (
  `num_eqpo` int NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_gpo2` int NOT NULL,
  `nom_equipo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`num_eqpo`),
  KEY `nom_equipo2_idx` (`num_gpo2`),
  CONSTRAINT `nom_equipo2` FOREIGN KEY (`num_gpo2`) REFERENCES `grupos` (`num_gpo`)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `partidos` (
  `semana` int NOT NULL,
  `num_eqpo_loc` int NOT NULL,
  `num_eqpo_vis` int NOT NULL,
  `goles_loc` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `goles_vis` int DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `num_eqpo_loc2_idx` (`num_eqpo_loc`),
  KEY `num_eqpo_vis2_idx` (`num_eqpo_vis`),
  CONSTRAINT `num_eqpo_loc2` FOREIGN KEY (`num_eqpo_loc`) REFERENCES `equipos` (`num_eqpo`),
  CONSTRAINT `num_eqpo_vis2` FOREIGN KEY (`num_eqpo_vis`) REFERENCES `equipos` (`num_eqpo`)
)
```

[image: IMAGEN RESULTADO]

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que unir la tabla de partidos con la de equipos, aunque en tu caso lo debes hacer dos veces puesto que tienes dos equipos. A cada tabla de equipos le asignamos un alias (un nombre: local y visitante). Para unir las tablas utilizamos la instrucción `INNER JOIN`, indicando la columna que une las dos tablas, en este caso es la columna `num_eqpo` de la tabla `equipos` y las columnas `num_eqpo_loc` y `num_eqpo_vis` de la tabla de `partidos`.

```
SELECT local.nom_equipo, visitante.nom_equipo, semana, num_eqpo_loc, goles_loc, num_eqpo_vis, goles_vis, (goles_loc = goles_vis) AS Ganador FROM partidos 
INNER JOIN equipos local ON partidos.num_eqpo_loc = local.num_eqpo 
INNER JOIN equipos visitante ON partidos.num_eqpo_vis = visitante.num_eqpo
```

Comment: ¿Cómo podría lograr que en el campo de `Ganador` se muestre el nombre del ganador o si fue empate?